# SublimeText3 doesn't recognize Scanner class

Tags: java, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using a custom build system to compile and run java programs.

The build system:

```
{
     "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0\\bin\\javac", "$file"],
     "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
     "selector": "source.java",
     "variants":
     [
     {
          "name": "Run",
          "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0\\bin\\java.exe", "$file_base_name"]
     }
     ]
}
```

This works perfectly as long as I never ask for input. This is the error I get with this simple program:

Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner leopard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = leopard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0\\bin\\java.exe', 'Test']]
[dir: C:\Users\yayu\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin]
```

My question is if there is any way to get the Scanner class working in SublimeText3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. As has been [documented here extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sublime+text+input), Sublime does not support input when running programs directly inside the editor (such as using the build system you have). However, there is a workaround on Windows: run your program through an instance of `cmd.exe` first.

```json
{
     "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
     "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
     "selector": "source.java",
     "shell": true,

     "variants":
     [
     {
          "name": "Run",
          "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "java", "$file_base_name"],
          "shell": true
     }
     ]
}
```

The `/k` option keeps the window open after your program has finished running, so you can inspect output, errors, etc. If you want it to close immediately, just use `/c` instead. I removed the full path to the `javac` and `java` executables as it's already in your `PATH`, according to the error message. It keeps the build system cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: I get this error: "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" when I try running it.

Comment: @yayu have you tried deleting the `.class` file, recompiling, and then running again? My knowledge of Java is somewhat limited, so I'm not quite sure what else to suggest. You might also want to try adding the `.exe` back on to the `javac` and `java` commands, just to see if that's the issue.

Comment: I did try deleting the .class file and recompiling. I added the .exe as well, but I still get the same error. If you think of something else, please let me know. I'll keep fiddling with it in the mean time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @yayu - OK, one more thing - see my edit above. I added `"shell": true` to both build and run commands. Hopefully that will make the difference!

Comment: Yes! It finally works! Can you explain what that line does? Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: `"shell": true` means that the command defined by `"cmd"` is executed through the shell - `cmd.exe` under Windows. `start` is not an external program, but an internal command of `cmd.exe`. Therefore, `"shell": true` needs to be set in order for the `start` command to work.